# Entity framework polling

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a website which uses polling to constantly get information from the API's I have setup using .NET and Entity framework. My database is hosted in AWS Aurora MySQL. Today when I used my MySql workbench to access my production database it said that there were too many connections.

In my knowledge:
1. Entity Framework manages opening and closing of connections
2. AWS automatically scales to user requests

Why am I getting this issue?

Is it a AWS issue or a .NET in application issue?

Comment: Does your code create connections recklessly, such as open a new one for each query? You may need to reboot your database instance to get access to it, and when you do, keep an eye on `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see if it starts to get clogged up with sleeping connections when you start to exercise your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points here:

**Point1:**

Entity Frameworks does manage connections, but that still depends how you use it.

Generally speaking, a DB context in EF is an IDisposeable object. That means, if you put it inside a "using" block, it will close connections and dispose the object for you. Something like this:

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
   [...]
}
```

Otherwise, if it is not inside a using block, you should always remember to dispose it. I would also explicitly close the connection for insurance.

**Point 2:**
AWS RDS does not scale automatically. You can choose your DB instance size at creation time, and after that you can change the instance type manually. You may even have some sort of automation to vertically scale it at run-time, but vertical scaling has its own limitations:

1. f your DB is in a single AZ, that means for changing the DB instance type you will have a down time, as the DB instance needs to shut down and restart.
2. If it is a Multi-AZ instance, still your existing connections will drop and your application needs to reestablish connections.